# How to determine what Redis cache serializer to be used?

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, redis, jackson

In my experience, I've used Redis cache serializers for `RedisCacheManager` as well as `RedisTemplate`. For `RedisCacheManager`, the default key serializer is `StringRedisSerializer` and the default value serializer is `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`. When it comes to `RedisTemplate`, the both default key and value serializers are `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`. Apart from that the `RedisTemplate` has hash key serializer and hash value serializer. As far as I know, the hashing is fully supported via Redis and therefore the hash and key value serializers are not applicable for spring caching. When it comes to Redis serializers, I was able to figure out the following implementations.

- `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer`
- `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`
- `StringRedisSerializer`
- `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer`
- `ByteArrayRedisSerializer`
- `GenericToStringSerializer`
- `OxmSerializer`

My concern is how to determine the suitable serializer for my use case. I clearly understand that when using `StringRedisSerializer`, I will not be able to serialize a java object and for that I'll have to use either `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` or `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer`. I also noticed that the `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` allows to set our own `ObjectMapper` which is very helpful when dealing with `JSON`. Determining the relevant serializer is fully depending on the use case and what type of values to be cached. However, I was not able to figure out a proper documentation where it is clearly distinguished these serializers. I think it would be very helpful to understand the difference of each serializer beforehand. That is my concern and thank you in advance for investing time to read my concern.